# Importing all files from a folder in react

Tags: reactjs, import, jsx

I am importing all SVG's from a folder in 'icons' through an index.jsx like the following line:

index.jsx:

```
export about from './about.svg';
```

Here goes the Import:
Button.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './MenuIcon.scss';
import * as IconID from './icons';

const Button = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="menu-icon" >
            <div className={'menu-icon__icon-wrapper'}>
                <IconID.about /> // This works great
                <IconID['about'] /> // This does not work
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Button;
```

Now to get a specific Svg e.g. I just call  in the return methode and everything works fine.

Now I want to load different SVG's like:

```
const svgName = 'back';

return (<IconId['back'] />);
```

How can i make this possible?

Comment: Why are you using <IconID.about /> over <img src={IconID.about} />? There is nothing, technically wrong with using array accessor over properties. (https://jsbin.com/jesonafuto/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Well actually this is how the project is build and it uses https://github.com/jhamlet/svg-react-loader to load the svg to the browser. I have to restructure the project to load svg's this way. If there is no alternative I would use url-loader and load svg to img but if there is another option this would be nice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `React.createElement` syntax for dynamic definition of element instead of JSX, as it only works with compile-time identifiers.

`React.createElement(IconId.back, {...props}, [...children])`

Answer (score 2):

*You can use context here*

```
const importAll = (r) => {
  return r.keys().map(r);
};

const allData = importAll(
  require.context("./icons", false, /\.svg$/)
)
```